# Keystonejs (version 4) list sortable option not reflecting on template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, content-management-system, keystonejs

I am trying to sort the order of the images on my client's list by name. They are sorted on the admin UI but this same arrangement is not reflecting on website's template

```js
const keystone = require('keystone');
const Types = keystone.Field.Types

const storage = new keystone.Storage({
    adapter: require('keystone-storage-adapter-s3'),
    s3: {
      key:process.env.S3_KEY,
      secret: process.env.S3_SECRET,
      bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
      region: process.env.S3_REGION,
      path: '/',
      uploadParams: { // optional; add S3 upload params; see below for details
        ACL: 'public-read',
      },
    },
    schema: {
      bucket: true, // optional; store the bucket the file was uploaded to in your db
      etag: true, // optional; store the etag for the resource
      path: true, // optional; store the path of the file in your db
      url: true, // optional; generate & store a public URL
    },
  });

const Clients = new keystone.List('Clients',{
    map: { name: 'name' },
    autokey: { path: 'slug', from: 'name', unique: true },
    sortable:true,

});

Clients.add({
    name:{type:String},
    logo:{ type: Types.File, storage: storage },
    website:{type:Types.Url}
})


Clients.register()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding an .sort() method when querying the list. When the sortable option is added to a new List a field called 'sortOrder' is created. So on my clients.js, I queried it like this:

```js
let clients = keystone.list('Clients');

view.query('clients', clients.model.find().sort('sortOrder');
```